# Sequential vs parallel solution

Tags: oracle, plsql, parallel-processing

I will try to present my problem as simplified as possible.

Assume that we have 3 tables in Oracle 11g.

```
Persons (person_id, name, surname, status, etc )
Actions (action_id, person_id, action_value, action_date, calculated_flag) 
Calculations (calculation_id, person_id,computed_value,computed_date)
```

What I want is **for each person** that meets certain criteria (let's say `status=3`)
I should get the `sum` of `action_values` from the `Actions` table where `calculated_flag=0`. (something like this `select sum(action_value) from Actions  where  calculated_flag=0 and person_id=current_id`).

Then I shall use that `sum` in a some kind of formula and update the `Calculations` table for that specific person_id.

```
update Calculations set computed_value=newvalue, computed_date=sysdate
where  person_id=current_id
```

After that `calculated_flag` for participated rows will be set to `1`.

```
update Actions set calculated_flag=1
where  calculated_flag=0 and person_id=current_id
```

Now this can be easily done sequentially, by creating a cursor that will run through Persons table and then execute each action needed for the specific person.

(I don't provide the code for the sequential solution as the above is just an example that resembles my real-world setup.)

The problem is that we are talking about quite big amount of data and sequential approach seems like a waste of computational time.

It seems to me that this task could be performed in parallel for number of person_ids.

So the question is:

Can this kind of task be performed using parallelization in PL/SQL?

What would the solution look like? That is, what special packages (e.g.  `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE`), keywords (e.g. `bulk collect`), methods should be used and in what manner?

Also, should I have any concerns about partial failure of parallel updates?

Note that I am not quite familiar with parallel programming with PL/SQL. 
Thanks.

**Edit 1.** 
Here my pseudo code for my sequential solution

```
procedure sequential_solution is
    cursor persons_of_interest is
        select person_id from persons
        where  status = 3;

    tempvalue number;
    newvalue  number;
begin

    for person in persons_of_interest
    loop
        begin
            savepoint personsp;

            --step 1
            select sum(action_value) into tempvalue
            from   actions
            where  calculated_flag = 0
            and    person_id = person.person_id;

            newvalue := dosomemorecalculations(tempvalue);

            --step 2
            update calculations set computed_value = newvalue, computed_date  = sysdate
            where  person_id = person.person_id;

            --step 3
            update actions set calculated_flag = 1;
            where  calculated_flag = 0 and person_id = person.person_id;

            --step 4 (didn't mention this step before - sorry)
            insert into actions
                ( person_id, action_value, action_date, calculated_flag )
            values
                ( person.person_id, 100, sysdate, 0 );
        exception
            when others then
                rollback to personsp;
                -- this call is defined with pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION:
                log_failure(person_id);
        end;

    end loop;

end;
```

Now, how would I speed up the above either with `forall` and `bulk colletct` or with parallel programming **Under the following constrains:**

1. proper memory management (taking into consideration large amount of data)
2. For a single person if one part of the step sequence fails - all steps should be rolled back and the failure logged.

Comment: Parallel processing is an extreme solution.  Have you considered set-based solutions rather than cursor loops?  Or `bulk collect` and `forall`?

Comment: @TonyAndrews its an idea...There are some problem though I am not quite sure how to resolve 1. possibly huge memory consumption  (may be some use of `limit` will remedy that) 2.with sequential approach I could commit per person. in that case if one person's operation fails - other are not affected - not quite sure how to achieve that with `bulk updates` as there are several tables updated per person. Is "set-based solution" that you mentioned, same as use of `bulk collect` and `for all` or is it something else? Could you provide in pseudo-code your proposed solution? Thanks.

Comment: @TonyAndrews why would one avoid parallel solution? The more I think about the particular problem the more I am getting convinced that use of `forall` and set based solutions for transaction-like operations (per person) could be quite cumbersome.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: In 25 years of Oracle development I have only rarely used any parallel processing.  It is only usually done in huge, probably data warehouse, databases and where the job in question has is the only thing running on a server with multiple CPUs at its disposal (no other users on the system at the same time). Is this your situation? How much is "quite a big amount of data"? **Billions** of rows?

Comment: @TonyAndrews Ok, so the number of rows is surely much less then billions ... a million probably (I will be given  an estimation at a later point) ... However the other criteria that you mention are kind of met . That is - this procedure will run solo (form one user only) and only twice or 4-5 times a year at a time that no other user is logged in the db. Now I am leaning toward parallel solution because it seem intuitively more clean solution. Besides I still cannot imagine how to do **transaction management** with `bulk collect`. `for all` and other set based solutions.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't understand your doubts about transaction management though? With bulk processing your transactions are larger, that's all - eg 1000 people's data processed per transaction.

Comment: How long would your process take without parallel processing?

Comment: @TonyAndrews I have been informed that we are probably talking about 30-40 million rows. My task is to convert legacy code / algorithm (non-plsql) into pl/sql  and the legacy code runs for about 3.5 hours. I haven't implemented the sequential  solution yet - so I do not know how long will it take to execute. You have a point regarding 1000 people's data transaction ... may be it's worth it to rollback 1000 people's transaction because of 1 person's problem ... but gain in speed, if all goes right.. Also, it is possible that some kind of hybrid solution is the answer here...

Comment: My advice would be to build a the simplest possible solution first, see how that performs, and only introduce the (in my view) complexity of parallel processing if the simple solution doesn't perform well.  The business logic will be the same in both cases, so you won't have wasted any time (but may find you can save time).  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I can propose the following. Let's say you have 1 000 000 rows in `persons` table, and you want to process 10 000 persons per iteration. So you can do it in this way:

```
declare
  id_from persons.person_id%type;
  id_to persons.person_id%type;
  calc_date date := sysdate;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100 loop
      id_from := (i - 1) * 10000;
      id_to := i * 10000;

      -- Updating Calculations table, errors are logged into err$_calculations table
      merge into Calculations c
      using (select p.person_id, sum(action_value) newvalue
               from Actions a join persons p on p.person_id = a.person_id
              where a.calculated_flag = 0 
                and p.status = 3
                and p.person_id between id_from and id_to
              group by p.person_id) s
         on (s.person_id = c.person_id)
      when matched then update
       set c.computed_value = s.newvalue, 
           c.computed_date = calc_date
       log errors into err$_calculations reject limit unlimited;

      -- updating actions table only for those person_id which had no errors:
      merge into actions a
      using (select distinct p.person_id
               from persons p join Calculations c on p.person_id = c.person_id
              where c.computed_date = calc_date
                and p.person_id between id_from and id_to)
         on (c.person_id = p.person_id)
       when matched then update
       set a.calculated_flag = 1;

      -- inserting list of persons for who calculations were successful
      insert into actions (person_id, action_value, action_date, calculated_flag)
       select distinct p.person_id, 100, calc_date, 0
         from persons p join Calculations c on p.person_id = c.person_id
        where c.computed_date = calc_date
          and p.person_id between id_from and id_to;

      commit;
    end loop;
end;
```

How it works:

- You split the data in `persons` table into chunks about 10000 rows (depends on gaps in numbers of ID's, max value of `i * 10000` should be knowingly more than maximal `person_id`)
- You make a calculation in the `MERGE` statement and update the `Calculations` table
- `LOG ERRORS` clause prevents exceptions. If an error occurs, the row with the error will not be updated, but it will be inserted into a table for errors logging. The execution will not be interrupted. To create this table, execute:

  ```
  begin
    DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG('CALCULATIONS');
  end;
  ```

  The table `err$_calculations` will be created. More information about `DBMS_ERRLOG` package see in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_errlog.htm#ARPLS680).
- The second `MERGE` statement sets `calculated_flag = 1` only for rows, where no errors occured. `INSERT` statement inserts the these rows into `actions` table. These rows could be found just with the `select` from `Calculations` table.
- Also, I added variables `id_from` and `id_to` to calculate ID's range to update, and the variable `calc_date` to make sure that all rows updated in first `MERGE` statement could be found later by date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I don't think that I can put all the steps into one statement (like merge above). In your solution  `Actions`'s `calculated_flag` is never updated to `1`. Also there is a 4th step (`insert`) that  I forgot to mention. Take a look at my edited version of question I added some code for a sequential solution...

Comment: @Plirkee There is no problem to add more statements. I updated my answer (the code and explanations), take a look.

Comment: Ok I see... However still my second constrain is not met. Assume that the 1st merge is executed flawlessly (no errors) but the 2nd merge or the 3rd insert fails for some reason (for some persons). Then I will have an inconsistency at my hands. I hope  you understand what I am trying to say ... those 4 steps for each person should behave as a transaction - all or nothing. I have no huge problem if for a number of persons their transactions fail. But there can not be partial failure for a specific person.